# Fill A Prescription

Tags: ellipsis, causatives

I am a little bit confused about the usage of the phrase "*fill a prescription*".

> 1. ***A patient*** filled his prescription.
> 2. ***The pharmacist*** filled a prescription.

Dictionaries suggest only the second one is correct.  But I did find usages on the web similar to the first sentence.  Is one of them wrong?

Comment: Literally, a patient cannot "fill" his own prescription, only a pharmacist can. Do you have any sources for the first example? Otherwise it is hard to understand the intent behind the statement.

Comment: @user3169 Here is another [example](http://www.pdr.net/pharmacy-savings/discount-card-for-patients/Profiles/): "When ***she filled her prescription*** at the pharmacy using her PDR Pharmacy Discount Card, the discount helped her to offset the cost of her medication."

Comment: OK, this would be a better quote to use in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Both usages are correct in American English.  The first usage means "A patient went to a pharmacist, and had the pharmacist fill the prescription."

Comment: So, the first sentence "*a patient filled his prescription*" is a corrupted version of "*a patient had his prescription filled* (by a pharmacist)"?

Comment: @Meatie -- Yes.  I would say it is a short version, not a corrupted version.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them seem correct to me as I've heard them both used. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fill) has a definition that supports the first sentence, though it's marked as being "mainly North American":

> Be supplied with the items described in (a prescription or order)
>
> > ‘she needed to fill a prescription’

It's even clearer in [Farlex via TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/filling+a+prescription), which has separate definitions:

> 1. To supply and sell a dose or set of doses of a medicine as prescribed to one by a doctor.
> 2. To go to or contact a pharmacy in order to buy a dose or set of doses of a medicine as prescribed by a doctor.